# Unwanted space before the first TOC entry

Tags: table-of-contents

I use the titletoc package, and this is how my chapter entries look:

```
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{2pc}}
{\thecontentslabel.\ }
{}
{\normalsize\titlerule*[12pt]{.}\contentspage}
[\addvspace{3pt}]
```

Notice that 2pc vertical space before the entry? This is great, *except that it also occurs for the first entry*. This is a problem, because it makes the entries appear 2pc farther away from the “Contents” chapter name than it actually should be.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\addtocontents` to counterbalance the unwanted space:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0pc]
{\addvspace{2pc}}
{\thecontentslabel.\ }
{}
{\normalsize\titlerule*[12pt]{.}\contentspage}
[\addvspace{3pt}]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{-2pc}}

\chapter{Test chapter one}
\chapter{Test chapter two}

\end{document}
```